# Cookie works in Chrome but not in IE or Safari?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cookies, browser

I'm using cookies with my log-in system and the system works on Chrome, but then when I go to IE or Safari, it's not working. For some reason the cookies are not being set, I've tried to echo them to no avail.

Here is the code that makes the cookies:

```
if(isset($_POST['log_in_iniator'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $log_in_checker_status = check_user_data($username, $password);
    if($log_in_checker_status == 'true'){
        //user has successfully logged in, create two cookies
        //cookie 1 username
        setcookie('username', $username, 0, 'http://shkeek.com');
        setcookie('loginstatus', 'true', 0, 'http://shkeek.com');
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        setcookie('loginstatus', 'invalid', 0);
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
 setcookie('username', $username, 0, 'http://shkeek.com');
```

To:

```
 setcookie('username', $username, (24*60*60), '/');
```

Or: (see below)

```
 setcookie('username', $username, (24*60*60), '/', '.shkeek.com');
```

Why:

You are setting the "expires" time to 0 seconds from now. Therefore Chrome is making a "session" cookie (will expire when you close the browser) and IE and FF will do exactly what you told them to do - expire any matching cookie.

The `(24*60*60)` is "one day"; 24 hours * 60 miniutes * 60 seconds from now.

For the "domain path" part, you only need to set the "/" for the current server and server path.

If you have more than one sub domain supported for the site, use `'/', '.shkeek.com'` instead. You then have support for `www.shkeek.com`, `shkeek.com`, `img.shkeek.com` and any other sub domain of `.shkeek.com`.

For more details, check the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)